# Installing natural package in a meteor application

Tags: meteor, nlp

For having natural language processing facility. Have added natural node package in my application using "npm install natural". But after installation while running the application using "sudo meteor", got some error about ""ReferenceError: require is not defined"". After googling found that need to do following steps:

1) Remove node_modules on the top of the root of the application (Done this part)

2) Added "natural": "0.1.27" in packages.json file also

3) Install npm using ""mrt add npm"". But getting following error after installing it in the application, while using ""sudo meteor"".

```
        => Meteor 0.8.1.3 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
```

Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.10
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.3.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.10
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `router`:
error: no such package: 'ui'

While building package `npm`:
error: couldn't read npm version lock information

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Any pointers what should be done. Not getting anything, this error taking my whole time. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running `meteor update`?

Comment: Yup, have done meteor update. Also tried to change version of it to 0.8.0, now getting stuck in syntacticalpart of "A template tag of type TRIPLE is not allowed here.". Any pointers what could be done

Comment: This is not the same issue. Can you show some code? TRIPLE are theses right? `{{{template}}}`

Comment: Html file having triple tag is :                                                    <input id='check' class="check" name="markdone" type="checkbox"  {{{ done}}} />Get Notifications                                                         Corresponding .js file is:Template.subscribedKeyword.done = function () {

};   . How to prevent this error from coming?. Also I upgraded the version to prevent that npm error. Are these not related to each other?

Comment: Simply use 2 braces. {{done}}

Answer (score 1):

To use NPM packages within your meteor application you need to first install meteor-npm
`mrt add npm`

You then have to add a `packages.json` file at the root of your project like so;

```
{
  "natural": "0.1.27"
}
```

When this file changes, meteor will automatically update its dependencies.

You can then use `var natural = Meteor.require("natural")`

Comment: Have done this addition in packages.json file. While installing npm using command that you have mentioned. After running the project, got the above mentioned errors. Also updated the project to 0.8.0 from 0.7.0.1, still getting error, what to do??