# Npm command not working

Tags: meteor

I have to install natural node in a meteor project. But for that I need to install npm so for that I am using this command "mrt add np". But it not showing anythiing means going in infinite loop. But when I tried to install natural node using command "npm install natural", it got install. Why so??

But for perperly installing natural I need to follow these steps:
 "[Installing natural package in a meteor application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831538/installing-natural-package-in-a-meteor-application?noredirect=1#comment36737582_23831538)" but when I am doing that basic command is not working. How can I proceed with rest of the things.

Any pointers please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Meteorite obtains all the packages from

`atmosphere.meteor.com:443`

which seems to be down at the moment. Npm doesn't depend thereon, that's why `npm install` works for you. A solution for you might be adding the git url to the package in the `smart.json` à la

```
"somepackage": {
    "git":"https://github.com/somegreatgithubber/somepackage.git"
}
```

Hope that helps, kind regards!

Comment: As I want to add natural package, so for that I need to add   "natural": {"git": "https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural"}. If it is correct, after adding that still meteor project is not working, showing some "referenceError: require is not defined". Any pointers please. Thanks!

Comment: Still showing error while running project as "ReferenceError: require is not defined". Same problem I am facing as in this post: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831538/installing-natural-package-in-a-meteor-application?noredirect=1#comment36737582_23831538". Please tell me what should be done

Comment: atmosphere.meteor.com is up again so maybe you just try `mrt add ..`