# natural package for natural language facility not getting installed in meteor package

Tags: meteor, nlp

I want to install natural package for natural language facility in a meteor project. Initially I tried to install using [this link](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural). It installed perfectly but when I ran my app, got error:

> ReferenceErros:require is not defined

For this I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831538/installing-natural-package-in-a-meteor-application?noredirect=1#comment36737582_23831538) ans solution not helped much.
Then, found on googling that need to install natural package on meteor app, `mrt add natural`. The link for that is [this](https://atmospherejs.com/package/natural).

But when I am installing using this command, I got error as:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:106
>   throw('Could not locate package.js within path ' +
>   self.source.packagePa ^ Could not locate package.js within path
>   /home/priya/.meteorite/packages/natural/NaturalNode/natural/d541ca394659521498ed36a7f6e03fef93163e53

Please give any pointers. I am stuck in this installation for so many days. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `npm` meteor package than individual wrappers. Those were necessary before, but now there's no need to use them and thus maintain them separately.

First, instal `npm` by running `mrt add npm`.

Then create `packages.json` file in your project directory. List your dependencies there:

```
{
  "natural": "0.1.27"
}
```

Finally, use `Meteor.require` to access it:

```
var natural = Meteor.require('natural')
```

Comment: Where to write this last line:Meteor.require('natural');???. Also, when I run this mrt add npm command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:106 throw('Could not locate package.js within path ' + self.source.packagePa ^ Could not locate package.js within path /home/priya/.meteorite/packages/natural/NaturalNode/natural/d541ca394659521498ed36a7f6e03fef93163e53" error is coming. I am not able to figure out why it is pointing out error in a file outside the project directory

Comment: The last line (or a similar one) is used to access the package, so you use it in a file where you need access. As for the error, it looks like something is wrong with your meteorite installation. Try upgrading it to the latest version, or uninstalling and installing again.

Comment: I followed these steps: sudo mrt uninstall....
sudo mrt uninstall --system....
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm....
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite.... Still not working what to do