# Error while installing natural node in meteor project

Tags: meteor, nlp

```
I am working on a meteor project. Have to use natural package for natural language facility. I installed that using 'npm install natural'. But when ran the project, got error as 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'.

Added this line: var abc=Meteor.require('natural'); in the file in which have to use it. But when I am running the project, it is showing error as:=> Started proxy.
=> Meteor 0.8.1.3 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

    While building package `router`:
    error: no such package: 'page-js-ie-support'
    error: no such package: 'HTML5-History-API'

-- When tried to install the above listed missing packages, showing error as: 

smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json, I got the following error after successfully installing various packages like natural, iron-router, paginated-subscription, router, accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown, spin. But after that showing following error. Why so?

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:106
      throw('Could not locate package.js within path ' + self.source.packagePa
                                                       ^
Could not locate package.js within path /home/priya/.meteorite/packages/natural/NaturalNode/natural/d541ca394659521498ed36a7f6e03fef93163e53


-- The packages in my project are: I don't understand here as router package is already listed then why showing error while running the project.??

 meteor list --using
standard-app-packages
bootstrap
router
accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
accounts-password
spin
paginated-subscription
email
insecure
iron-router
npm
```

Please guide me in this direction. This error is becoming a recursive kind of error. Have broke my head in this problem but still stuck. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [natural package for natural language facility not getting installed in meteor package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956239/natural-package-for-natural-language-facility-not-getting-installed-in-meteor-pa)

Answer (score 0):

You have a package called `Natural` (not sure which) which isn't built to the correct packages specifications or has been modified somehow.

This can't be fixed that easily, you would have to contact the author of the package to fix it or modify it yourself. I can't find `NaturalNode` on atmosphere so its likely a custom package.

You might want to make the rest of your app work to debug fixing it though. To do that you need to remove this package

Remove the files and folders in `~/.meteorite/packages`

Look through your packages smart.json and remove the offending package (natural). and run `mrt update`. And remove the rest of the code in your app relating to natural that might stop your app booting up.

From what it looks like you've cloned `https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural` into meteorite somehow. You would have to [look at how to build a package](https://atmospherejs.com/docs/publishing) for meteor.

The files you have used are an npm module and don't just work with meteor if you copy the files in. You have to make a compatible meteorite package for it to work. Or use [meteor-npm](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) to use the npm module in your app directly.

[This project](https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo) may also help you get started as an example of how to make a wrapper for an npm module to use with meteor

Comment: When I am running "mrt add npm", I got following error:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/meteor.js:154
          throw "Error running a command: " + error;
                                            ^
Error running a command: Error: Command failed: => Errors while scanning packages:
While building package `router`:
error: no such package: 'page-js-ie-support'
error: no such package: 'HTML5-History-API'
....What to do to prevent this??

Comment: Akshat!... Removed natural package from ~/.meteorite/packages and smart.json. Now when running the app, it is showing following error: W20140603-13:34:10.496(1)? (STDERR) /home/priya/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140603-13:34:10.497(1)? (STDERR)       throw(ex);
W20140603-13:34:10.497(1)? (STDERR)             ^
W20140603-13:34:10.498(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W20140603-13:34:10.498(1)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/natural/node_modules/apparatus/lib/apparatus/classifier/bayes_classifier.js:23:12......What to do now?

Comment: The package.js that it is listing is inside this directory: ....~/gbproject/packages/npm/package.js. Because earlier, I was getting error regarding non searching of this file in project. Can see npm.require('path'). Should I need to add "npm.require('natural')" in this file or where I want to use this package??